# Intercepting navigation in React-Router v6

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-native-webview

Currently, I have a SPA served inside of a React Native webview using using `react-native-webview`. I want to restrict the routes that users can navigate within the SPA, and produce different navigation behaviors in React Native instead.

I wonder if it is possible to add a pre-navigation callback in React Router to "intercept" route navigation, check the existence of a window property, specifically `window.ReactNativeWebView`, and simply do nothing if it exists.

I explored potentially doing something with `useLocation`:

```js
const location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  if (window.ReactNativeWebView) {
    window.location.back();
  }
}, [location.pathname])
```

but that did not work since we are using `HashRouter` in our SPA implementation and `location.pathname` doesn't change. It also feels pretty janky to force a back navigation, so I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would likely require creating a custom router component and custom history object in order to work with RRDv6, but [`history.listen`](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#historylistenlistener-listener) might be helpful here.